# Difference between Neo4j Dijkstra and shortestPath performance?

Tags: rest, neo4j, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a database populated with random data with social relationships like person-> attended -> university,  person1 -> friends-> person2 etc.
There are 4 types of nodes. My database has about 3M nodes and 12M edges.

When I try querying paths between 2 random nodes using the REST API 
I get the response from shortestPath algorithm in about 3-4 secs. But running the same query with Dijkstra never returns.

I understand Dijkstra is expensive but is there something I might be doing wrong?

URL -  http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/499052/paths

payload for shortest path-

```
{ "to": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/296431", "algorithm": "shortestPath", "max_depth":4 }
```

payload for dijkstra-

```
{ "to": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/296431", "cost_property": "weight", "algorithm": "dijkstra", "max_depth":4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing anything wrong, the performance difference between `shortestPath` and `dijkstra` is that large unfortunately. If your weights are all 1 then I would definitely recommend using `shortestPath`.

Comment: Is it something specific to Neo4j. Dijkstra doesn't return paths even if I leave it for an hour or so. I saw the source for neo4j and it seems they are using fibonacci heaps, so the implementation should be O(E+VlogV). I wonder what other factors could influence it to be so slow.

Comment: The termination conditions for `dijkstra` when asking for multiple paths are a bit sloppy. Basically this can cause a lot more unnecessary traversal.  This is something we are looking into right now.

How many paths do you find between the nodes in your example?

Comment: allShortestPath gives me a single path at max_depth 4. My graph has a small diameter so I don't expect the path length to be more than 5-6 maybe. I think the best way would be to write a custom PathExpander that cuts off dijkstra's expansion for longer paths. Please let me know if there are any other workaround you may suggest.

Comment: I tried the PathExpander approach. Instead of never returning now it takes about 10-15 minutes. Is there anything you would suggest? Increasing the heap size maybe.

Comment: That sounds like a very good idea (nice to see that it worked). Ideally the PathExpander would terminate as soon as it no longer can "beat" the shortest found path.

Comment: I've been working on an improvement for Dijkstra now. It should run better a lot better (still quite far from ShortestPath unfortunately).
You can pull a snapshot from m2.neo4j.org

Comment: I am not sure how to use m2.neo4j.org. If you can help me with that I will run the tests again. Thanks